# Why does default move constructor need default-deleter of class used in unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unique-ptr, move-constructor

The following code correctly compiles with Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <memory>

namespace NS
   {
   class SomeOtherClass;

   class MyClass
      {
      public:
         MyClass();
         virtual ~MyClass();
      private:
         std::unique_ptr<SomeOtherClass> m_someOtherClass;
      };
   }

int main()
   {
   auto mc = NS::MyClass();
   }
```

This is because of a bug in Visual Studio 2013, in which the initialization of `mc` in `main` is directly optimized without checking for a move constructor.

In Visual Studio 2015 this doesn't compile because the move constructor must exist, so we change the code to this:

```
#include <memory>

namespace NS
   {
   class SomeOtherClass;

   class MyClass
      {
      public:
         MyClass();
         virtual ~MyClass();
         MyClass(MyClass&&) = default;
      private:
         std::unique_ptr<SomeOtherClass> m_someOtherClass;
      };
   }

int main()
   {
   auto mc = NS::MyClass();
   }
```

And again this compiles.

But, if we now want to export the DLL, then compilation again fails.  This is the modified code:

```
#include <memory>

namespace NS
   {
   class SomeOtherClass;

   class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
      {
      public:
         MyClass();
         virtual ~MyClass();
         MyClass(MyClass&&) = default;
      private:
         std::unique_ptr<SomeOtherClass> m_someOtherClass;
      };
   }

int main()
   {
   auto mc = NS::MyClass();
   }
```

This is a part of the compiler output:

```
memory(1193): error C2027: use of undefined type 'NS::SomeOtherClass'
test.cpp(5): note: see declaration of 'NS::SomeOtherClass'
...
memory(1194): error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type
memory(1195): warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'NS::SomeOtherClass'; no destructor called
```

It seems that the default-generated move-constructor requires being able to destruct `SomeOtherClass`.  This is strange because `MyClass` has a destructor, in which the full definition of `SomeOtherClass` is known.

So why doesn't this compile when exporting the DLL?  And why does the default move constructor require knowing the definition of `SomeOtherClass`?

Comment: I cannot tell you why (good question though). you can probly fix this when you have `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&&) = default;` in your cpp file and only the declaration in the header file.

Comment: Can't you write `NS::MyClass mc;` in `main()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` requires a complete type, specifically to handle the deletion.

Your defaulted move constructor is inline and could be represented by the following pseudocode:

```
MyClass(MyClass&& other):
    m_someOtherClass(std::move(other.m_someOtherClass));
{}
```

This requires `SomeOtherClass` to be a complete type, to be able to move the default deleter templated on it.

> [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa0d9ste.aspx) on defining inline C++ functions with dllexport
>
> You can define as inline a function with the dllexport attribute. In
>   this case, the function is always instantiated and exported, whether
>   or not any module in the program references the function. The function
>   is presumed to be imported by another program.

I don't have VS2015 handy, but just declaring the constructor in the class and defining it in a translation unit where `SomeOtherClass` is defined should do the trick:

```
   class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
      {
      public:
         MyClass();
         virtual ~MyClass();
         MyClass(MyClass&&);
      private:
         std::unique_ptr<SomeOtherClass> m_someOtherClass;
      };
   }
```

file_containing_~MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&&)=default;
```

Comment: Before your answer, I was in the assumption that SomeOtherClass didn't have to be destructed.  But as you point out, it does.  After the release of the unique_ptr, the 'other' instance will contain a nullptr, and although deleting a nullptr does not require the destructor, the implementation of the destructor of the unique_ptr will still contain code to call the destructor.  So although it is never called in this case, it is needed.

Comment: @pat No, that is not it, move does not destroy source it just nulls it.

Comment: @krz no, that is not a permitted move constructor.  It must be `MyClass(MyClass&& other):m_someOtherClass(std::move(other.m_someOtherClass)){}`.  And even in move-ctor, the move ctor has no need to `.reset`, so I do not believe that is permitted...